# Queue Color Modifications

Tags: apex, visualforce, code, css

Our inbound emails are worked out of the Service Console. Messages coming in will end up in a Support Queue and then escalated/passed to different queues or technicians when appropriate. We receive several requests that are generated from a contact form. Additionally, our newer support agents will update case information (product, contact info, etc) and leave messages in the queue for more advanced agents to complete later.

[image: Example of Case Highlighting Concept]

I would love to have any of these details modify (maybe background or border color) how the entry appears in the case Queue. If it could alter the display so that we would know what product specialist needs should look at it, or if the message has been in the queue for over 12 or even 24 hours.

My theory is that maybe I can invoke a CSS template to make these be used for the specific display/color changes that I'm looking for. At the same time, I feel it might not be as simple as all of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a custom formula field which would change based on whatever logic you want with the case. The following example is from Salesforce's documentation on formulas:

> **Color Squares for Case Age**
>
> This formula displays a 30 x 30 pixel image
>   of a red, yellow, or green, depending on the value of a Case Age
>   custom text field.
>
> ```
> IF( Case_Age__c > 20,
> IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif", "red", 30, 30), IF( Case_Age__c >
> 10, IMAGE("/img/samples/color_yellow.gif", "yellow", 30, 30),
> IMAGE("/img/samples/color_green.gif", "green", 30, 30), ))
> ```

You would then add this formula field to your list view in the Service Console and you should be good to go. Comment below if you have any questions.

Here's a link to the documentation, it's in the section titled "Image Links": https://na2.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_useful_formula_fields.pdf

This guy also has a nice list of icons and images available for your use by default with Salesforce: http://free-121d5f44d20-121d603d1c5-121ee2b8103.force.com/force2b/salesforceicons